# How to include components of psutil in py2exe that py2exe can't find?

Tags: python, module, include, py2exe

I am using py2exe on windows 7 to make an app using psutil. I am using python 2.7. I am making a single file executable. When I try to compile the python python program with psutil, near the end it says:

```
The following modules appear to be missing
['_psutil_bsd', '_psutil_linux', '_psutil_osx', '_psutil_posix', '_psutil_sunos', '_scproxy', '_sysconfigdata', 'builtins']
```

However, the program compiles fine. When I run the compiled program, it crashes and generates a log file:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "TaskManager.py", line 27, in 
  File "zipextimporter.pyc", line 82, in load_module
  File "psutil__init__.pyc", line 135, in 
  File "zipextimporter.pyc", line 82, in load_module
  File "psutil_psmswindows.pyc", line 14, in 
  File "zipextimporter.pyc", line 98, in load_module
ImportError: MemoryLoadLibrary failed loading _psutil_mswindows.pyd

I have tried listing in the options part of the setup:

```
"includes": ["_psutil_mswindows.pyd"]
```

as well as just

```
"includes": ["psutil"]
```

I have also tried including all the modules py2exe listed as missing. With the exception of including psutil, which didn't do anything, py2exe could not find these files.

There are a surprising number of similar questions on this topic online, but none of them have good answers (if any answers at all) and many of the errors are not quite the problem I have.

Update: strangely enough, I found _psutil_mswindows.pyd in build\bdist.win32\winexe\collect-2.7 of py2exe's build directory. I guess for some reason it isn't getting packaged properly.

Comment: Just hit the same problem. It looks like the pyd file is packaged correctly, it is found in library.zip. I am investigating.

Comment: This problem occured, when I packaged psutil with py2exe on 64-bit installation of Windows 8 and then tried to run the exe file on Windows XP Home Edition 32-bit. What I did was, I moved the whole build process to Windows XP (32-bit) and the problem solved itself. I found that suggestion somewhere on the net yesterday, so the idea about the origin of the bug is not mine. We're talking about an issue, where the file _psutil_mswindows.pyd gets packaged (can be found in library.zip).

Comment: I actually just used pyinstaller instead. It worked fine with a bit of work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All these issues come from py2exe including a bunch of system dlls.

Adding the following list of excludes. (Mainly the last 4). Solves this issue.

```
dll_excludes=['msvcr71.dll', "IPHLPAPI.DLL", "NSI.dll",  "WINNSI.DLL",  "WTSAPI32.dll"]
```

You can take a look/cross reference the .dll with those found in your system folder for a list of which ones it is included that should not be present.

Comment: Thank you again, this solved our issue as well with freezing psutil by including this option

Answer (score 2):

I met this:

```
ImportError: MemoryLoadLibrary failed loading psutil\_psutil_windows.pyd
```

It is a little bit different from the question in filename.

After reading the source code of psutil, I figured out the root cause:
**The target Windows platform of psutil depends on which platform it is built
on.**

The following code exists in _psutil_windows.c, suggesting GetIfEntry2 is referenced. You can easily confirm this by running depends.exe to load _psutil_windows.pyd on Windows XP.

```
#if (_WIN32_WINNT >= 0x0600) // Windows Vista and above
        SecureZeroMemory((PVOID)pIfRow, sizeof(MIB_IF_ROW2));
        pIfRow->InterfaceIndex = pCurrAddresses->IfIndex;
        dwRetVal = GetIfEntry2(pIfRow);
#else // Windows XP
        pIfRow->dwIndex = pCurrAddresses->IfIndex;
        dwRetVal = GetIfEntry(pIfRow);
#endif
```

And setup.py generates macros according to the current system environment like this:

```
# Windows
if WINDOWS:
    def get_winver():
        maj, min = sys.getwindowsversion()[0:2]
        return '0x0%s' % ((maj * 100) + min)

    macros.extend([
        # be nice to mingw, see:
        # http://www.mingw.org/wiki/Use_more_recent_defined_functions
        ('_WIN32_WINNT', get_winver()),
        ('_AVAIL_WINVER_', get_winver()),
        ('_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS', None),
        # see: https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil/issues/348
        ('PSAPI_VERSION', 1),
    ])
```

So the options to solve this problem are:

1. Build psutil on a Windows XP Machine, or
2. Modify setup.py to use the target Windows platform version as we want.